# Can I use sObject.get() conditionally, to only get the value of the field if the field exists on the sObject?

Tags: apex

'myField' may or may not exist on the record. Depending on some User customization. In th following scenario, the field does not exist but I want to get it if it exists and don't get it if it does not.

I don't see anything in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get), so I probably cannot do what I'm trying to do, but can I do something like the following:

```
(String)sObject.get('myField' || '')
```

The above fails with the following:

```
Logical operator can only be applied to Boolean
```

I've also tried:

```
if(sObject.get('myField') != null){
    (String)sObject.get('myField')
}
```

But I get an error at runtime saying myField does not exist on my object.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check the describe call:

```
if(sObject.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().containsKey('myField')){
  return (String)sObject.get('myField');
}
return null;
```

Or, you could use try-catch, but that's kind of "expensive" in CPU time (about 80ms on a thrown exception):

```
try {
  (String)sObject.get('myField');
} catch(sObjectException ex) {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: This might of been a recent addition, but there is this [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getPopulatedFieldsAsMap](getPopulatedFieldsAsMap). From what I saw with your initial answer, `fields` has field names even if they weren't retrieved via SOQL.

Comment: @Zerkz Sorry about the previous comment. Looking back, I think I was more focused on "is there a describe call for this." The getPopulatedFieldsAsMap actually came out in 2016. `getPopulatedFieldsAsMap` is great for limiting yourself only to fields that have been queried and have a non-null value.